# 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found : FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, podfile

[image]

I am trying to run my flutter app on ios device and I am getting this error.

Comment: Which version of "url_launcher" did you use? Use latest version.

Comment: Yep. @Aman Mishra Please include `url_launcher`'s version and `flutter doctor -v` for details. Have you tried `pod update` inside `ios` folder where your `Runner.xcworkspace` exists?

Comment: I am using the latest, Still getting the error

Comment: Have you tried these commands `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get` and `pod install`?

Comment: @DholaHardik Yes, I have tried the above steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do is to clear the .pubchache file in flutter sdk file which I downloaded. It worked for me and the build was successfull.